# jQuery Window Opener Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this repeated multiple times on my main page (it's dynamically generated).

```
<input type='text' name='pois[]' />
<a onclick="window.open('file.php', 'searchPoi', 'width=800, height=500')" class='btn btn-default' id='searchPoiBtn'>Edit</a>
```

What I'm trying to do, is on the popup page that opens (file.php), modify the contents of the closest text box to that button (on the parent page), based on what the user selects in the popup.

I know how .closest() works, but can't get it working right when dealing with the parent window.. Any ideas?

Comment: `I know how .closest() works`.  Can you elaborate on this?  Because nothing about this issue right now suggests to me that the solution would use closest.  Maybe `prev()` but not closest.  Also how are you returning data from the popup back to the page with this markup on it?

Comment: well not sure how the pop up would have any clue what link opened it.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is: 1. get the id (or something) of the link that opened the popup. 2. find the closest input to that opener link, and modify the value

Comment: How are you passing the information back from the popup to the parent page?

Comment: Easiest thing is give it is an id when it is generated and pass that id along as a parameter to the get request.

Comment: That's what I'm not sure of.. I know you can use window.opener to talk to the parent page, but not really in the way that I'm wanting to do

Comment: So, just so it's clear.  At this point, this question is essentially, "I have this markup, and I want to do X.  Tell me how to do it."  That's very broad.  If you have specific questions about part of this problem, please ask about those, rather than just asking for a solution.

Comment: I'm not asking for the exact code of how it should be done. I stated how I have things set up now and what I've tried messing with. I'm just asking for suggestions on what way I should try to do this, or if it's even possible. And I thought my question was pretty specific, wanting to modify data in the parent window.

Comment: All you have given us is the markup with the inline binding.  The solution to the problem involves opening the popup, communicating back to the parent any data needed, and resolving that data back to an element on the page.  None of those pieces have been given in the question showing any sort of an attempt.  If you tried something that did not work, show what didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Here is a simple self-referential example using cross document messaging, since you mentioned that in one of your comments. I'm including my original notes at the bottom, which discusses other communication technologies that are available.

If this is saved as the body of a document `message.html`, it will try to open itself in a new window, and when opened in a new window it will try to send a simple static string back to the parent window. Obviously you could use whatever code you want in the popup to send back a message on any event.

```
<input type="text" />
<a class='new-tab'>click me</a>

<script>
    (function () {
        var input = null;
        window.onmessage = function (m) {
            console.log(input, m, m.data);
            if (input && 'value' in input) {
                console.log('we have an input', m.data);
                input.value = m.data;
            }
        };
        var el = document.querySelector('a.new-tab');
        el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            input = this.previousElementSibling;
            var cwin = window.open('message.html', 'searchPoi', 'width=800, height=500');
        });

        var owin = window.opener;
        if (owin) owin.postMessage('contents to put in the input', '*');
    })();
</script>
```

Original answer:

Since you are opening a new browser window/tab, this is not going to be an easy solution. Browsers are generally designed to "sandbox" pages (for example, would you really want a website you had open in your browser to be able to access your bank account website that you had open in another tab?)

However assuming you have control of both windows, you can use various technologies to communicate between tabs.

Some involve going through a server (WebSocket, EventSource, long polling XHR). Your subpage could send a message to your server, and if the "parent" page had an open WebSocket etc, it could forward the message back to the original page.

Other methods allow direct communications between windows/tabs, such as [cross document messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), [channel messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Channel_Messaging_API), [broadcast channels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API), etc.

Browser compatibility could also be an issue, depending on what browsers you're needing to support. Best bet is to pick one, such as cross document messaging, and play around with it. See if you can get it to do what you want.

Also, you're going to probably want a more robust onclick event than you can manage inline like that. You're going to need to keep track of the `this` or the `event.target` from your click, at least long enough to identify the adjacent `input`. (And you can't use `closest` to identify the closest sibling. `closest` deals exclusively with parent/ancestor tags.)